# Getting ID of the new record and making it a part of the saveURL parameter

Tags: visualforce, urlhacking

I have a button that calls a URL for creating a new record while going through the SF native record type selection screen.

Once the new record is created, I want the saveURL to call an apex page, and pass the new record's ID as parameter for that page.

How can I get the newly created record's ID and make it a part of the saveURL parameter?

Comment: Is the button a custom button of URL type? Is the save done by a user action, if so can you override your save button on the record you are creating thereby redirecting it to another page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution!  Apparently, salesforce automatically adds a parameter called newId to the saveURL.

Just as an example here is my use case - I have an object called Compliance that lives on Opportunity (has a lookup to Opportunity, and is created from Opportunity) and has a many-to-many relationship with Quote and Sales Order (custom objects).  The many-to-many relationship is fulfilled via a junction object called Compliance Link, and which has lookup fields to Compliance, Quote, and Sales Order.  Users wanted a way to create Compliance records not only from the Opportunity, but also from Quote or Sales Order.

Solution:
Create a button on Quote and on Sales Order, that calls a standard URL for creating a new Compliance record, but then runs some code to create a Junction object record.  First it takes user to the standard record type selection page, then it takes the user to the new record EDIT page.  Finally, on Save, it redirects the user to a visualforce page (which is never displayed but does some processing).  The page's controller gets various parameters from the page's URL, creates a new junction object, and takes the user to the newly-created Compliance record's page.

**URL behind the button:**

```
{!$Site.Domain}/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=01IZ00000000zbt&retURL=%2F{!Quote__c.Id}&save_new_url=%2Fa6Z%2Fe%3FCF00NZ0000000nuQS%3D{!Quote__c.Opportunity__c}%26CF00NZ0000000nuQS_lkid%3D{!Quote__c.OpportunityId__c}%26retURL%3D%252F{!Quote__c.Id}%26saveURL%3D%2Fapex%2FComplianceCreateAndLink%253FquoteId%253D{!Quote__c.Id}
```

**Explanation:**

**{!$Site.Domain}** - have to use this because the record's view is overridden with a visualforce page.

**/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=01IZ00000000zbt** - takes you to the recordtype selection page for the object identified by the **ent** parameter

**&retURL=%2F{!Quote__c.Id}** - standard return URL, takes you back to the record where you clicked the button.

**&save_new_url=%2Fa6Z%2Fe%3FCF00NZ0000000nuQS%3D{!Quote_*c.Opportunity*_c}%26CF00NZ0000000nuQS_lkid%3D{!Quote_*c.OpportunityId*_c}%26retURL%3D%252F{!Quote_*c.Id}%26saveURL%3D%2Fapex%2FComplianceCreateAndLink%253FquoteId%253D{!Quote*_c.Id}** - takes you to a standard new object edit page, while prepopulating a lookup field for you.  In the **save_new_url** is another parameter - **saveURL**, value of which is doublly-url-encoded.

The magic **saveURL** (double encode it): calls an apex page, while passing it a the original source object ID (Quote ID).  Salesforce automatically adds one more parameter to it on invocation - newId: "/apex/ComplianceCreateAndLink?quoteId={!Quote__c.Id}

When Salesforce takes you to this URL, it will look something like this (note the newId parameter that got added automatically):
https://cs11.salesforce.com//apex/ComplianceCreateAndLink?quoteId=1QWE3000000000133&newId=18HG00000000012345

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="ComplianceCreateAndLinkController" action="{!link}">
```

Controller:

```
public class ComplianceCreateAndLinkController {

public Map<String, String> params = null;

public ComplianceCreateAndLinkController() {
    params = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters();

}

public PageReference link() {
    String complianceId = params.get('newId');
    String quoteId = params.get('quoteId');
    String sOrderId = params.get('sOrderId');

    Compliance_Quote_Link__c newLink = new Compliance_Quote_Link__c();
    newLink.Compliance__c = params.get('newId');
    newLink.Quote__c = params.get('quoteId');
    newLink.Sales_Order__c = params.get('sOrderId');
    newLink.Sales_Order_Number__c = params.get('sOrderNumber');
    insert newLink;    

    return new PageReference('/' + newLink.Compliance_Audit__c);
}
```

}

Note - I guess all this could have been done with Javascript also.

Comment: How could this be done with Javascript?  I need to do pretty much the same exact thing but we only have professional edition so would not be able to create a controller class for the VF page.  Thanks!